# How to open the android quick notification setting

Tags: java, android

In android **i want to open android notification quick setting** in android program   after a lot of searching from all resources found code for opening notification bar only.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work and, if so, what app is it for? Also, have you seen this working in any other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this code relies on non-public API's. It is not guaranteed to run correctly on all Android devices.

```
try {

     Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
     Class<?> statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");

     // expands the notification bar into the quick settings mode
     // - replace expandSettingsPanel with expandNotificationsPanel
     // if you just want the normal notifications panel shown
     Method expand = statusBarManager.getMethod("expandSettingsPanel");
     expand.invoke(service);

} catch (Exception e) {
     // do something else
}
```

Don't forget the required manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: hey adelphus! i know for expanding the code for expanding the status bar but i wanna open notification quick setting(in which wifi, bluetooth,airplane mode,user profile etc quick settting reside)

Comment: @ShivamRatan I'm unclear about the problem here. The code I have posted shows the notification bar with all the WiFi, BT, , etc quick buttons visible (at least it does on my Nexus 4). Note that "expandSettingsPanel" is different from "expandNotificationsPanel" which is what most other people suggest. Does it not work for you or were you expecting something different? Could you describe how you would normally navigate to the screen you want to see (or post a picture)?

Comment: @adelphus, is there a way to expand the edit panel instead?